# I need to change the color using onClick or a click handler, don't know which is better

Tags: javascript

I have the

```js
export const colors = {
  red: "#d52027",
  blue: "#1875f0",
  yellow: "#dbeb39",
};
```

AND I want to use red for example to change the color of an icon(svj) which is

```js
export const StyledIconMedia = styled(Icon)`
  background-color: ${colors.blue};
  padding: 13px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
`;
```

Comment: What's your actual problem/question?

Comment: hi, so if i use <StyledIconMedia onClick={()=>.....} I want to change the colour of the icon using the data from above.

Comment: You should be setting up event handlers using [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Inline [event attributes like `onXyz` are legacy and should not be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these).

Comment: thx il try to do some more research and I apologise if I disturbed anyone.

Comment: @johnny You certainly didn't disturb anyone. Sometimes people will ask for more info if the question isn't clear. It's to help us help you. That's what we're here for.